# Returning the specific string Any() is finding

Tags: c#

What i am trying to do here is search in a few .txt files for certain string that may exist in the HTML of a webpage, the code is working fine:

**Code:**

```
var b_c = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\Blogs\blogs.txt");
var f_t = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\Forums\forums.txt");

if (b_c.Any(html.Contains))
{
    platform_type = "BLOG";
} 

if (f_t.Any(html.Contains))
{
    platform_type = "FORUM";
}
```

The code works as intended, what i'm trying to do now is return the specific string that is found, 1 text file is 20 strings long, it would be good if i could see the string that was marked as found in the HTML, i cannot think of a way to do this, ior is it even possible with the code as it is? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `FirstOrDefault()` an option?

Comment: Please provide your full source code. What is html.Contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing

```
var found = b_c.FirstOrDefault(html.Contains);

if(found != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(found);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Contains("your string"))?
In the example below you can do anything you like with the variables.
Also I strongly suggest you to read more about naming conventions in C#. You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions for example.

```
var b_c = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\Blogs\blogs.txt");
var f_t = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\Forums\forums.txt");

var blog = b_c.FirstOrDefault(html.Contains);
if (blog != null)
{
   platform_type = "BLOG";
}
var forum = f_t.FirstOrDefault(html.Contains);
if (forum != null)
{
   platform_type = "FORUM";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys! ```FirstOrDefault``` it is :)